# How to solve an equation from input expression?

Tags: python, math, input, expression, equation

The input expression has to be in a + b and a - b form and the question asks to solve those equation.

(there is space before and after + and -)

So an example would be:

```
expression: 2.7 + 1000
1002.7
```

I only got to this point:

```
import math

text = input("expression: ")
```

Comment: This appears to be a homework or challenge question. What specific requirements do you have for valid solutions? What have you tried to actually evaluate the expression? You may also want to take a look at the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if we are guaranteed that the expression contains space before and after the "-" or "+"

```
import math

text = input("expression: ")

expression_list = text.split()

print(expression_list)

if expression_list[1] == '-':
    print(float(expression_list[0]) - float(expression_list[2]))
```

Similarly, you can do it for addition, multiplication and division as well.

Comment: User input is **never** guaranteed

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The questioner has written that there is a format for the input. So, I guess this will work for this particular question.

Comment: For testing purposes or for this question - yes. IRL - no. User can i. E. unintentionally make a typo - and without any validation /sanitization you may end up doomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` method. This is a way of literally running expressions.

Answer (score -1):

One Simple solution for you.

```
import math
text = input("Expression: ")
output = eval(text)
print("Answer : ", output)
```

I have tested + - * / these four. try more. Read about eval Function

Comment: I did not learn eval Function so I cannot answer the question with eval...

Comment: did you read search string?